# A program to analyze startup times

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I used to have a program that would watch the startup processes as they load, time how long each one took to startup, and then spit out a report on which startup processes are slowing the loading process the most.

I can't remember the name of the software, so I'm hoping somebody here knows of it off the top of their heads..

Comment: Which OS? (Why do I need 15 chars?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[BootVis](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/BootVis.shtml)** is a performance trace visualization utility that you can use with Windows XP systems.

use this for analasys only, not for optimization! Bootvis does not work with Vista or later.

MSDN's **[Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx)**, a much better set of tools than the old Bootvis utility. At its most basic, you can use the tools to provide you with a similar graphical display of boot performance which was provided by Bootvis.

and then there is Passmark **[AppTimer](http://www.passmark.com/products/apptimer.htm)** to analyze the startup behaviour of applications.

Comment: I keep hearing that BootVis doesn't have any optimization power, but in the Trace menu I see 'Optimize System'. Wonder what that does.

Comment: Bootvis' 'Optimize System' feature has become obsolete since Windows XP.

Comment: AppTimer made me think about Startup Delayer: http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startdelay

Answer (score 5):

On Linux you can use [Bootchart](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootchart/) which will log the entire boot process and give a nice graphical representation of the results. It is popular enough to be included in most distributions' default repositories so you shouldn't have much trouble installing it.

[image: Bootchart example]

Comment: <blink>Advertisement</blink>

Answer (score 3):

Respecting this is a really stupid old question - here is a great new tool for it. 
http://www.soluto.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were thinking of [Bootvis](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5034622.html).

Comment: too late     :P

Comment: @Molly not true anymore: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/podcast-66/

Comment: what is       ?

Comment: Answers with the same amount of votes are now arranged randomly.

Comment: I saw a tool on TV the other day that did the same thing as Bootvis but was MUCH MORE descriptive, down to details of each service and what ORDER they start. I wish i could remember the name of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try BootHawk. http://www.affini.co.uk/boothawk#.Ul0WsqNwZMs

32 & 64 bit, XP, windows 7&8.

BootHawk is an analysis and on-going monitoring tool that empowers organisations to understand and measure, how the PC boot-up and user login processes are performing. BootHawk was created from more than a decade's experience of identifying and rectifying the root cause of extended boot-up and login periods. BootHawk breaks the complex boot-up and login process down, into accurately measured and individual components that are visualised and easily interpreted through graphical web-based reports .BootHawk is the ONLY tool that measures the end-to-end process performance, from PC start-up to the desktop being visible.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) has gained the feature of 'Boot time logging of all operations'. `Options` menu > `Enable Boot Logging`.