# Windows XP startup log file (with startup times)

Tags: windows-xp, boot

My Windows XP hangs for 15 minutes after log on. Desktop and all icons are shown, but mouse pointer turns to a hourglass when I hover the taskbar and the Start button, and programs cannot be started. (Well, some can, but, for example, Task manager is not one of them).

After ~15 min., startup sound is played and I can use it normally from that point on.

**Is there a place where I can find which driver/program is being loaded after log on, for such a long time?**

This is a PC which has been working like this for ages, so system restore wouldn't change anything. I could disable startup programs one by one, but there is a lot of them and every time I do a restart I need to wait for 15-20 minutes to try the next one.

Comment: I'd add that there's a very old similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/40205/a-program-to-analyze-startup-times.  My suggestion wasn't out at the time though and is by far the best tool for the job.

Comment: Disable all startup programs, if it boots fast, enable them one at a time and reboot each time, you will find the offending startup program if this is the cause. Much faster doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) is probably exactly what you're looking for.  Basically it runs at startup and logs EVERYTHING that happens and how long it takes, and presents it neatly.  You can then tweak as necessary.